# Is there a rule of thumb for worrying about flash garbage collection?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My sprites are 4KB (png)- black squares  and I probably creating about 200 of them throughout the game plus 2 small textfields each- should I worried about getting garbage collection right? 277 jpg Kb image resides permanently(full basic colour) and about 30 Kb gifs of images. No moveiclips.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how much animation you're doing with these objects. at the same time, garbage collecting can cause rendering to pause momentarily... If you're seeing this issue, then consider using memory saving techniques such as object pooling to keep garbage collection to a minimum.

Otherwise, let the garbage collector do what it's designed for, and leave it.

Comment: Does alpha and visibility count as animation? I could probably just reuse to reduce need to kill sprites.

Comment: You should probably use Adobe Scout to detect what's taking more time for rendering/execution and memory (and how much actual garbage collection you're getting). It's the best way to determine chokepoints on your content.

Comment: Yes, alpha: 0 and visible: false objects which are set to animate, still get rendered and consume memory. Try it on a movieclip with looping animation, set visible to false and look at the redraw regions in a debug flash player

Answer (score 0):

Thumb of rule will be remove all pointers from object (event listeners and child objects) and remove it from parent.

To be more specific read this - http://www.skinkers.com/2010/10/08/memory-management-in-air-as3-flash-garbage-collection/

monitor your memory over time with a simple tool as : http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/09/01/moviemonitor-an-as3-performance-monitor-with-10-1-features/   if you discover issues you can find for more complex profiling tools.

You usually don't want to force garbage collection but follow these common rules and let flash player do the rest